# MEAN STACK APP deployment HEROKU issue MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server

Tags: angular, mongodb, heroku, mean

Can't find a way to connect to MongoDB in order to deploy the application. Gives me an error
" MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017" What could go wrong? Connected to 8080 server and still gives an error.

app.js

```js
    const MONGODB_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/members'

    mongoose
      .connect(
        MONGODB_URI,
        { useNewUrlParser: true },
        { useMongoClient: true }
      )
      .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))

    var Users = require('./routes/users')

    app.use('/users', Users)
    const Post = require('./model/post')
    //API end point for fetching the list of blog posts. Since for db Mongo is used, Mongoose client added to connect the db with the app.
    app.post('/api/post/getAllPost', (req, res) => {
        mongoose.connect(url, { useMongoClient: true } , function(err){
          console.log(err - 'error here')
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log("connection established successfully")
            Post.find({},[],{ sort: { _id: -1 } },(err, doc) => {
                if(err) throw err;
                return res.status(200).json({
                    status: 'success',
                    data: doc
                })
            })
        });
    })

    app.listen(port, function() {
      console.log('Server is running on port: ' + port)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

At first try accessing your database by mongodb compass community there you may get a connection string to connect to your database locally..

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/supercampus?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass%20Community&ssl=false',
{ useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true },
(err,res)=>{
   if(err) console.log(err)
   else{
    console.log("connected")
   }    
})
```

for heroku deployment you need an online option like mongodb atlas which is free

Comment: Thank you. I can connect locally, works perfectly fine. But remotely something is missing

Comment: moving with turtle steps. I was missing the beginning path /', added path to the app.js. But now got a new error "MongooseError: 3rd parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` must be a function, got "object"

Comment: if local works fine now try accessing online database they will provide you url string to connect .. try accessing it with compass community first and then use it in api.